# How do I configure a target group to reach a service in my EKS fargate cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have installed the AWS Load Balancer controller on the cluster but when I create a load-balanced service it creates a network load balancer which does not work.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ######
  namespace: mb
  annotations
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: ########
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "ip"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ip-address-type: ipv4
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 4546
  selector:
    app: ######
  type: LoadBalancer
```

When I try to reach the endpoint I get the following response:

```bash
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I have tried disabling the node ports on the service, I have tried using an application load balancer, I have tried creating an ingress to route traffic to my service and I have tried updating the target groups route to the node port.

However, the problem still persists and I still cannot work out how to create a load balancer to reach the workload in the eks fargate cluster.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to deploy an nginx ingress to enable traffic to reach your service. Follow this guide: https://github.com/nginxinc/helm-charts

Comment: I am using a load balancer, I do not need an ingress.